# How to make a one key for all values in dictonary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, items

I have a list:

```
List_ = ["Peter", "Peter", "Susan"]
```

I want to make a dictonary like this:

```py
Dict_ = {"Name": "Peter", "Count": 2, "Name": "Susan", "Count": 1}
Dict_ = {}
Dict_new = {}
for text in List_:
    if text not in Dict_:
        Dict_[text] = 1
    else:
        Dict_[text] += 1
for key, values in Dict_.items():
    Dict_new["Name"] = key
    Dict_new["Count"] = values
print(Dict_new)
```

It is printing only last ones:

```
{"Name": "Susan", "Count": 1}
```

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter for counter

Comment: You can't do that.  A key can only appear once in a dictionary.  Try the `collections.Counter` class -- that will give you a dictionary where the names are the keys and the counts are the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the implementation that you can use according to what you would like :

```py
from collections import Counter

# Your data
my_list = ["Peter", "Peter", "Susan"]

# Count the occurrences
counted = Counter(my_list)

# Your format
counted_list = []
for key, value in counted.items():
    counted_list.append({"Name": key, "Count": value})

print(counted_list)
```

And output will be :

```
[{'Name': 'Peter', 'Count': 2}, {'Name': 'Susan', 'Count': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, a dictionary can only have each key *once*.

You may want a *list of dictionaries*, built with help from `collections.Counter` and a list comprehension.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> List_ = ["Peter", "Peter", "Susan"]
>>> [{'name': k, 'count': v} for k, v in Counter(List_).items()]
[{'name': 'Peter', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'Susan', 'count': 1}]
```

In addition to using `collections.Counter` you could use a `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for n in List_:
...   d[n] += 1
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Peter': 2, 'Susan': 1})
>>> [{'name': k, 'count': v} for k, v in d.items()]
[{'name': 'Peter', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'Susan', 'count': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
List_ = ["Peter", "Peter", "Susan"]

dict_ = {}
for name in List_:
    if name in dict_:
        dict_[name] += 1
    else:
        dict_[name] = 1

print(dict_)
```

Generates the following output where key is the name and value is the count.

```
{'Peter': 2, 'Susan': 1}
```

Comment: `collections.defaultdict` provides a nicer way to accomplish this.

Comment: I'll surely check that.